# Get highest and lowest number from returned Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, coldfusion

I am converting something from coldfusion to PHP and Im stuck on something.  I am querying a mysql db and then I want to find the highest and lowest value returned.  You can see an example of the table returned below.

In this example I would want min to equal 2 and max 43

[image: returned table]

In coldfusion I used

```
<cfset tagValueArray = ListToArray(ValueList(getCloud.NUMBER_OF_TIMES))>
<cfset max = ArrayMax(tagValueArray)>
<cfset min = ArrayMin(tagValueArray)>
```

But I cant figure out how to do this using php.

I have the db call:

```
$gettotalMiles = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tfml_food, LOWER(tfml_food), COUNT(*) as number_of_times
FROM tbl_fm_log 
WHERE tfml_food != ''
GROUP BY (tfml_food) having count(*) > 1");

$min = ???;
$max = ???;
```

I have tried looking for a listtoarray and valuelist equivalent but Im stuck

Comment: this is a matter of mysql. Use min and max mysql functions in your query

Comment: thanks Botea Florin - would this work as I am counting within the query, its not just a standard select

Comment: You could probably do it with a subquery or two. Either that or if you order the query by the count value, then you can easily grab the beginning end of the results in PHP to find the largest and smallest.

Comment: thanks ADyson - could you elaborate on getting the largest and smallest please?

Comment: Why, which bit of my description was confusing or seemingly incomplete to you? I'm happy to try and clarify if you can explain where you were unable to understand.

Comment: The answers and duplicates already provided pretty much cover it anyway

Comment: @mesharp if you have have a table with max 20-40 entries and you need to retrieve these entries anyway for other logics, you can calculate min and max using an usort/loop. If there is more results on that table, and you only need a chunk of them, but also max and min, I suggest you make an extra query for retrieving them

Answer (score 1):

Although I think I'd recommend doing this at the database level, too, you can also just iterate over the array. If you dataset is very large, this might be a performance issue, but shouldn't be for small to medium sets (probably). For larger sets a single `for` loop might be better instead

```php
$data = [
    ['food' => 'banana', 'count' => 43],
    ['food' => 'bananas', 'count' => 3],
    ['food' => 'cheese strings', 'count' => 5],
    ['food' => 'tea towle', 'count' => 2],
];

$minValue = array_reduce(
    $data,
    static fn($min, $row) => min($min, $row['count']),
    PHP_INT_MAX
);

$maxValue = array_reduce(
    $data,
    static fn($min, $row) => max($min, $row['count']),
    PHP_INT_MIN
);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/bEWXn

If you also want to keep track of the actual *row* that has the least and greatest values, you can just a single `array_map` and grab all of that:

```php
$minRow = null;
$maxRow = null;
$minValue = null;
$maxValue = null;
array_map(
    static function ($row) use (&$minValue, &$maxValue, &$minRow, &$maxRow) {
        if (null === $minValue || $row['count'] < $minValue) {
            $minValue = $row['count'];
            $minRow = $row;
        }

        if (null === $maxValue || $row['count'] > $maxValue) {
            $maxValue = $row['count'];
            $maxRow = $row;
        }
    },
    $data
);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/2FApR

If, as @ADyson noted, you sorted your main query using a standard `ORDER BY` you can then just grab the first and last items in the array using `reset` and `end`

```php
$firstRow = reset($data);
$lastRow = end($data);

var_dump($firstRow, $lastRow);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/d1BMR